# How to make GridView works well in landscape mode

Tags: android, gridview

I'm having problem in making GridView works well in landscape mode. Its `android:stretchMode="columnWidth"` doesn't seem to work well in landscape mode.

### Portrait Mode

[image]

As you can see, I have 20x20 square grids, which is being fit nicely into the screen. (Although there's imperfection on right edge, I can ignore it at this moment)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start"
            android:id="@+id/start_button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Random"
            android:id="@+id/random_button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:id="@+id/clear_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="20"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:background="#ffc0c0c0"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### Landscape Mode

[image]

However, the 20x20 square grids doesn't fit nicely into the screen. I do not want the grid view to be scroll-able. I want to entire 20x20 square grids visible in entire screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start"
            android:id="@+id/start_button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Random"
            android:id="@+id/random_button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:id="@+id/clear_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="20"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:background="#ffc0c0c0"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**May I know what I had did wrong, which makes Landscape mode doesn't look as good as Portrait mode?**

Note, in order to make the grid view item looks square, I use the following custom class as grid view item.

```
public class SquareTextView extends TextView {

    public SquareTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public SquareTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public SquareTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

The complete source code can seen from https://github.com/yccheok/GameOfLife

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by extending GridView (without android:stretchMode). In my own GridView I put the following code at onMeasure:

```
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1)
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        else {
            int myWidth = ((View)getParent().getParent()).getHeight();
            if (myWidth > 0) {
                View parent = (View)getParent();
                myWidth -= parent.getPaddingBottom() + parent.getPaddingTop();
            }
            int measure = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(myWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            super.onMeasure(measure, measure);
        }
    }
```

The trick is to get top most view for myWidth and to add all paddings to myWidth